# Headless testing on safari browser running on ios

Tags: kubernetes, testing, safari

I was reading that [safari is now the second most used browser](https://www.neowin.net/news/statcounter-microsoft-edge-is-no-longer-worlds-second-desktop-browser/).
This got me thinking... can I run a jenkins worker on ios? Ideally I'd like to run on an ipad, but being able to run headless tests of an angular application in safari to ensure that it looks and works as expected is my ultimate goal. Can it be done?